# how can energy conservation equation be different in different situations?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

Neglecting potential and kinetic energy: energy conservation equation in a closed system is dU=Q-W and in an open system with steady flow is dU+d(PressureEnergyPV)=Q-W or in other words dH=Q-W. How can we consider pressure energy in the second case and ignore it in the first case?

Comment: It's possible that in different situations we have different constraints. If the volume of a system isn't changing, no work is being on the system done so $PdV = 0$.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Who limited about contraints and who said that the above equations work when P=constant or V=constant, etc? The above equations are working ALWAYS (neglecting potential and kinetic energy etc). They are the 1st law in closed system and SFEE (steady flow energy equation) in open systems respectively. And I don't understand who downvoted my question, ENOUGH with the nazi abuse here, IS THERE A MODERATOR???

Comment: anyone????????????

Comment: You need to give specific definitions to $Q$ and $W$, otherwise it's impossible to give a specific answer.

Comment: I found the answer. the d(PV) is the work done to push new mass in the system

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. the d(PV) is the work done to push new mass in the system

Answer (score 0):

It is just understanding the system: closed or open. A closed system doesn't interact with the environment, hence there is no change in pressure and volume. In other words, no external work is done on the system neither by the system. 
In the second case, there is pressure change due to interaction with environmental, hence work is done by the system or on the system. That's why pressure and volume changes are inevitable in the second case.